# Runtime error with debug build of project using MySQL Connector/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

I am using the MySQL Connector/C++ in my project for interaction with the MySQL database. The project compiles fine. However, when I run it I get an error

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD30B16D in ProjectName.exe: 
Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000000036FC2A0.
```

on the first line using the database. In this case I am executing a MySQL statement

```
sql::Statement* stmt = mSqlCon->con->createStatement();
stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..."); // Unhandled exception
```

When I compile for Release, everything works fine and no errors are thrown.

**My environment:**

- Windows 7, 64bit
- Visual Studio Express 2012

**Visual Studio project settings and libraries that might be relevant:**

- Preprocessor definitions: `_DEBUG;_MBCS;_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`
- Runtime library: `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`
- Basic Runtime Checks: `Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu) (/RTC1)`
- MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.6 (Release version)
- Boost Version 1.59.0

**My thoughts:**
This error occurred after I started using the boost library. This required to change some project settings, like preprocessor definition `_DEBUG` (which should be used for debug builds anyway, but was not used before to be able to build the connector). **So I think the problem is using the release version of MySQL Connector/C++ in the debug build of the project.** Everything works fine in the release build. However, I cannot find any debug version of the connector, nor can I build it myself or reinstall it with debug libraries... Is there another solution to my problem (or did I not search good enough)?

I read that there should be a `debug` folder in my MySQL folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.6\lib`, but it only contains an `opt` folder with the release build (which I am using).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, the problem is behind linking a project in Debug configuration with the Release library inside the opt folder. All you have to do is compile yourself the source code of the library in Debug configuration:

1. From the [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/), click on Select Platform, click on Source Code and download the windows version of the library
2. [Download and install CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) if you don't have it
3. Open a command prompt and change directory to the directory of the source code you downloaded
4. Type `(path\to\)cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` and run it; this way you are telling CMake to build a project that you can compile with the version 14 of Visual Studio (you can choose other versions, if you want to have a look type `cmake -h`) for a x64 Machine with Debug configuration.
5. At this point you should see some Visual Studio Projects in the library source folder- open the file `MYSQLCONNCPP.sln`. Change the output file type to static if you wish to create a static library.
6. Go to Solution Properties and only select the `MYSQLCONNCPP` project to build.
   a) Now go to Project Properties, and add `HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` to the Preprocessor Definitions (this prevents timespec redefinition)
   b) Add `/EHsc` to C++ -> Command Line (this prevents errors related to the exception handler)
   c) Change the project's Runtime Library to match the one you want to link the library to: for instance in my case I had to set it as `/MDd`
7. In case of other errors, check if all the Project Properties that CMake has built are well written: it might have had issues with some paths and file names with spaces inside.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. It happens because of discrepency in the configuration. The client application can be debugged if the mysql wrapper is a separate .lib file. If the Mysql release version has been downloaded and installed then you need to build a wrapper to connect/query etc and export it to other projects as a release .lib. The Mysql can be debugged using trace option provided. 
[MYSQL DEBUG TRACE C++](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-debug-tracing.html)